# spring-cloud-stream-kafka configuration: instanceCount & instanceIndex

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Running spring-boot `1.5.7.RELEASE` program using spring-cloud `Dalston.SR4`.
Worked myself through cloud-stream [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-SNAPSHOT), especially regarding kafka-binder usage, but am still unclear on some configuration aspects:

1. Do we really need to set `spring.cloud.stream.{instanceCount,instanceIndex}` when we're *consuming* from kafka brokers? I can't see why this would be required, given `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channel>.group` is set. Or is it safe to say these 2 properties are only required if `cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channel>.autoRebalanceEnabled` is set `false`?
2. Is there any benefit in setting `cloud.stream.default.consumer.partitioned: true` for kafka consumers?
3. Bonus: what's the difference between `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.auto.offset.reset` and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.startOffset`? Is it simply latter configuring offset-reset per channel? In any case, neither of these two are picked up, and `auto.offset.reset` value is still reported during startup as `earliest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Correct; it's only needed if manual partition assignment is being used.
2. Not really on the consumer side; but on the producer side, for example, if you need strict ordering - e.g., if you want all "orders" for customer "foo" to go to the same partition; you also need appropriate partitioning configuration. On the consumer side (for Kafka), it will just ensure there is a `group` provisioned.
3. `startOffset` is to override the global setting. There have been some bug fixes in the order these properties are applied [example here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/ec3f79fce8194cff56e5fda76b6e2b65e97d9ade#diff-b0b05f37655e15c59cb8dfee2cc5353d). What version are you using? The fix is in the 1.3.0 release; it's also on the 1.2.x branch but not yet released; we need a 1.2.2.RELEASE for it to be available; please open a github issue for that, if you can't move to 1.3.

Comment: I'm on `1.2.1.RELEASE`, so easiest path is to move to 1.3. Thanks for yet another quality reply.